# xslt: Getting value from book xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a book xml file, it contains multiple section tag and multiple article-title tag. And i need to get value of each article-tag value with corresponding section title.

My XML looks like this:

```
<root>
<article>
<series-title content-type="section-heading">Reviews</series-title>
</article>
<title>
<article-title>Post-epilepsy stroke: A review</article-title>
</title>
</root>
<root>
<article>
<series-title content-type="section-heading">Original Research</series-title>
</article>
<title>
<article-title>Prognostic implications of the Ankle Brachial Index</article-title>
</title>
</root>
<root>
<article>
<series-title content-type="section-heading">Editorial</series-title>
</article>
<title>
<article-title>What is NODDI and what is its role</article-title>
</title>
</root>
<root>
<article>
<series-title content-type="section-heading">Reviews</series-title>
</article>
<title>
<article-title>An update on the comorbidity of ADHD and ASD</article-title>
</title>
</root>
<root>
<article>
<series-title content-type="section-heading">Editorial</series-title>
</article>
<title>
<article-title>Occipital nerve stimulation and beyond</article-title>
</title>
</root>
```

And my output should be:

```
<h2>Reviews</h2>
<h3>Post-epilepsy stroke: A review</h3>
<h2>Original Research</h2>
<h3>Prognostic implications of the Ankle Brachial Index</h3>
<h2>Editorial</h2>
<h3>What is NODDI and what is its role</h3>
<h2>Reviews</h2>
<h3>An update on the comorbidity of ADHD and ASD</h3>
<h2>Editorial</h2>
<h3>Occipital nerve stimulation and beyond</h3>
```

And the thing is, i am using only one template match condition.

Can anyone help on this:

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="/this/root">
   <h2>
      <xsl:value-of select="article/series-title"/>
   </h2>
   <h3>
      <xsl:value-of select="title/article-title"/>
   </h3>    
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and in this solution, all your root tags should be in a "this" tag.